# SQL Union All with order by and limit (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, union-all

In the following query I get syntax error:

```
SELECT <property1>, <property2>
FROM <table1> 
ORDER BY <condition> LIMIT 1
UNION  ALL
SELECT <property1>, <property2>
FROM <table2> 
WHERE <condition> ORDER BY <condition> LIMIT 1;
```

> syntax error at or near "UNION"
>   LINE 4: UNION  ALL

Each of the `SELECT` stand alone executes fine. My guess is about the `ORDER BY... LIMIT 1` maybe?

Comment: Might be the ORDER BY clauses.  Since you're using UNION, the ORDER BY will need to be applied afterward.

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag, because it does not support `LIMIT`.

Comment: You list two different platforms.  on one of those platforms this would by a syntax error -- on the other it would work.  which one are you using?

Comment: Actually it's postgresql

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Wrap each query with `()`:

```
(SELECT <property1>, <property2>
FROM <table1> 
ORDER BY <condition> LIMIT 1)
UNION  ALL
(SELECT <property1>, <property2>
FROM <table2> 
WHERE <condition> ORDER BY <condition> LIMIT 1);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/60265/0)**</kbd>

You could also order final query:

```
(SELECT 'a' AS col
ORDER BY col LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT 'b' AS col
ORDER BY col  LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY  col DESC
```

Answer (score 9):

The first answer of @lad2025 is correct,
but the generalization just under is not correct because  must be the whole condition, desc clause included.

This is the correct code :

```
(SELECT 'a' AS col
ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'b' AS col
ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1
```

otherwise you select only le highest of the two lowest col of select 1 and select 2 (if any)
(and not the highest of all the cols)
and you must not forget the LIMIT 1 at the end too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT <property1>, <property2>
FROM <table1> 
LIMIT 1
UNION  ALL
SELECT <property1>, <property2>
FROM <table2> 
WHERE <condition> ORDER BY <condition> LIMIT 1;
```