# How to use ORDER BY and LIMIT together with UNION

Tags: postgresql

This works

```
SELECT * 
    FROM foo
UNION
SELECT *
    FROM bar
```

This gives me a "syntax error near UNION".

```
SELECT * 
    FROM foo
    ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1000
UNION
SELECT *
    FROM bar
    ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1000;
```

Why is that? How to UNION tables with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Union All with order by and limit (Postgresql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352296/sql-union-all-with-order-by-and-limit-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place each half of the union into a separate subquery:

```sql
(SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM bar ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too, englobe your statement in a Select

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY random() limit 10) as dt1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM bar ORDER BY random() limit 10) as dt2
```